# Wordpress wp-admin/install.php is not opening properly on windows 10

Tags: php, wordpress, installation, wamp, windows-10

So, I have worked with wordpress 3 or 4 times and last time I had a problem opening install.php it was due to me not knowing how to work with "wamp-server".

Today I was going to start a new project but it´s not working properly.

I have set-up wp-config.php and tried to open wp-admin/install.php but all it does is showing the code from install.php.

I am working with wamp this time again, had some trouble starting it due to Skype using port80, but fixed that.

I have, since friday, uppgraded my computer to windows 10. I´m hoping thats not the problem but at the same time dreading that it is..

Hope someone can give me a hand. I'm not an expert at all. I am from sweden, but  everything on my computer is in english so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: create a file and only try a `echo 'something'; ` to test the php parser.

Comment: Simply: start your server and access the file through the server (like entering the URL in a browser :)

Comment: i found this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use Microsoft Edge?

Microsoft Edge runs with network isolation by default for security reasons.

To enable loopback and debug your localhost server, launch Edge and type in the address bar :

```
about:flags
```

then there are some options like this:

```
Developer Settings

X Use the Microsoft Compatibility Lists
X Allow localhost loopback (this may expose your device to risks)
```

These two options must be checked.